# Need explanation for error np.concatenate message "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: numpy, runtime-error, concatenation

The following throws error

```
oness = np.ones((100000, 8))
np.concatenate(oness, oness)
```

np.concatenate needs brackets to work otherwise throws :

```
     10 oness = np.ones((100000, 8))
---> 11 np.concatenate(oness, oness)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)
```

The following works:

```
oness = np.ones((100000, 8))
np.concatenate([oness, oness])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definition for concatenate:

```
numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)
```

When you're writing `np.concatenate(oness, oness)` the second `ones` is being interpreted as the input to `axis`, which leads to the type error. But when you write `np.concatenate([oness, oness])` or `np.concatenate((oness, oness))` the inputs are interpreted correctly as `a1, a2` and are concatenated along the default `axis=0`.